# I make no sense

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> My start sounds Greek
>
> My middle leads a life of two-toes
>
> My end will break your bones

What am I?

Comment: Congrats on your first puzzle! A quick note: "first time" comments, like [greetings, introductions, and thank yous, should not be included](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950) in your question unless they're pertinent to the actual puzzle, as they have no lasting value. We've edited your post to remove them, and (if necessary) the title has been changed. Feel free to edit further if you dislike the details of what we've changed, but please *don't* put the "(first puzzle)" back. You could say it's your first puzzle *in a comment* if you like. (This message will self destruct.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it

> Fiddlesticks

My start sounds Greek

> Fi sounds like the greek letter phi

My middle leads a life of two-toes

> iddle sort of looks like idle which is what a two-toed sloth is for a majority of its lifetime

My end will break your bones

> Sticks and stones may break my bones.

Comment: Yes, that's it! The title of the question was meant as a clue as well, if course.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Oligodactyly?

The start is a Greek prefix

> oligo

Before being changed,

> the condition leaves me with only two toes

To change,

> bones must be broken during surgery to add new digits

Comment: Very nice idea, but no

Answer (score 1):

Could it be

> Pizza

The start sounds greek

> Pi is a greek letter

The middle leads a life of two toes

> Two-toed sloths are associated with sleeping and laziness "zz" is also a sound associated with sleeping or laziness.

However the last line doesn't seem to quite fit.  Perhaps it is something else related.

Comment: Unfortunately no.